# Slicing of python os.listdir()

Tags: python, slice

Can I make a slicing in os.listdir()? To take only a number of elements.

Comment: Sorry, I'm beginning with python. I didn't think It was possible to use "[:]" out of a function like g.d.d.c user did.

Comment: In Python you can chain operations as long as it makes sense based on the preceding return type.  In this case, `os.listdir()` returns a list, which makes slice notation on it valid.  If it returned a generator instead you'd need to convert it to a list somehow in order to be able to slice it.

Comment: @g.d.d.c: I've strong bases of the C language and it's not easy at first to get a view of python's reasoning. thanks

Comment: Even if not, you could just store the result somewhere and then slice that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why not:

```
>>> os.listdir(os.getcwd())
['CVS', 'library.bin', 'man', 'PyLpr-0.2a.zip', 'pylpr.exe', 'python26.dll', 'text']
>>> os.listdir(os.getcwd())[3:]
['PyLpr-0.2a.zip', 'pylpr.exe', 'python26.dll', 'text']
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `os.listdir(path)` returns a list, you can use slice notation on the result. For example, you can use `os.listdir(path)[:5]` to get the first 5 results:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('.')
['f1', 'f10', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9']
>>> os.listdir('.')[:5]
['f1', 'f10', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']
```

See [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) for a comprehensive overview of slice notation.